# How do I print multiple pages of text in C using the Windows GDI API?

Tags: winapi, printing, gdi

I'm working on a project to support simple printing of text in Windows, written in C and using the GDI API. The code below works just fine if the amount of text fits on a single page, but it will fail if the amount of text exceeds one page--usually just a blank page will print. I cannot figure out how to parse the text buffer to print out the amount of text that will fit on one page, and then carry over to subsequent pages until the buffer is complete. Can someone provide an example or sample code to assist?

Current code below is below:

```
static int WinTextPrint(char *buffer){

PRINTDLG pd;
HDC hDC;
TEXTMETRIC tm;
HANDLE printhandle;
int result;
DOCINFO di;
HFONT hFont;
char * cline;

result = 0;

/* Initialize print dialog. */
ZeroMemory( &pd, sizeof(pd));
pd.lStructSize = sizeof(pd);
pd.hwndOwner = GetDesktopWindow();
pd.Flags = PD_RETURNDC | PD_NOPAGENUMS;

if (PrintDlg( &pd) == TRUE) {
    hDC = pd.hDC;
    if (hDC == NULL) {
    result = 1;
     return result;
   }

    ZeroMemory( &di, sizeof(di));
    di.cbSize = sizeof(di);
    di.lpszDocName = "Text Output";

    hFont = (HFONT) GetStockObject(ANSI_FIXED_FONT);

    /* Set up the current device context. */
    SetMapMode(hDC, MM_TEXT);
    SelectObject(hDC, hFont);

    /* Work out the character dimensions for the current font. */
    GetTextMetrics(hDC, &tm);
    yChar = tm.tmHeight;

    if (StartDoc(hDC, &di) > 0) {
    StartPage(hDC);
            printhandle = SelectObject(hDC, hFont);
            RECT r = {
                0,
                0,
                GetDeviceCaps(hDC, PHYSICALWIDTH),
                GetDeviceCaps(hDC, PHYSICALHEIGHT)
            };
            DrawText(hDC, buffer, -1, &r, DT_NOPREFIX | DT_WORDBREAK);
           EndPage(hDC);
        EndDoc(hDC);
        DeleteDC(hDC);

        result = 0;
        return result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance for assistance.

Comment: I don't happen to have a sample handy, but `DrawText` has an option flag, which makes it not do any output but instead return the size of rectangle needed to draw the text. You can use that to see if the text fits on the page and, if not, do pagination as needed, with some effort.

Comment: `DT_CALCRECT` it is.

Comment: You can use `DT_CALCRECT` or [`GetTextExtentPoint32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gettextextentpoint32w) function to calculate the size of your corresponding text rectangle, and then view the rectangle Whether it fits the page size. When calling [`DrawText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtextw), adjust the parameter `c` according to the required size to ensure the text length of each page.